# Lodash isEqual method does not give expected result

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

```
const car = new Map([['100','200']]);
const bike = new Map([['200','100']]);
_.isEqual(car,bike); // true ???
car.get('100'); // "200"
car.get('200'); // undefined
bike.get('100'); // undefined
bike.get('200'); // "100"
```

Even though these two objects are not the same it returns true from isEqual method?

Comment: The current documentation claims it supports maps – which version of Lodash are you using?

Comment: confirmed on Lodash v4.17.10

Answer (score 2):

That's a known bug, and it is supposed to be fixed in `v5`. Read here: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/3428